# Retry Logstash Input after Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm currently using the jdbc plug-in to ingest data from an Oracle database into Elasticsearch every hour on the hour. I've noticed that sometimes the data fails to be ingested and when I check the logstash log file I see an error similar to the one below:

`{:timestamp=>"2015-11-28T08:00:00.309000-0500", :message=>"Exception when executing JDBC query", :exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseDisconnectError: Java::JavaSql::SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection>, :level=>:warn}`

It appears the logstash input failed because of a connection error, but I was wondering if there was a way to tell logstash to retry an input a certain number of times? So, for example, if it fails logstash might try again two more times. Thanks!

Comment: The jdbc input filter has no such parameters that I see.

Comment: Yea, I opened an issue on their Github page about adding this feature. I will post the outcome of that issue when it is resolved.